# Get gtk widget name

Tags: gtk, themes

I'm writing a GTK-Theme that is pretty dark. It works with most programs but some toolbars look pretty strange (in Bluefish and NetBeans for example).

Now I need to get the name of the toolbar widget to write a workaround.

Comment: [GtkToolbar](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkToolbar.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Parasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/), although I never used it so I cannot say how it works. Alternatively, you can use the ever working [good old way](http://bluefish.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bluefish/trunk/bluefish/).

Comment: Thank you for the Link to Parasite I think it will help me finding the widgets ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do Bluefish and NetBeans even use Gtk? Not sure what you would in that case, otherwise here is a list of widgets: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeArt/Tutorials/GtkThemes.

Comment: Bluefish uses Gtk but NetBeans uses Swing with the Gtk "Look-and-Feel" I believe.

The workaround for NetBeans would look similar to this:
widget "*netbeans*" style "light-toolbar"

But I need to know the widgetname to apply the style.
But thx for the Link ;-)